# Why is this layout animation not working?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, framer-motion

[The animation that I tried to replicate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyg5Lpl6AiM)

timestamp for the code: **34:15-34:45**

timestamp for the animation demonstration: **34:47-34:54**

It is easier to visualize through the link,
but bascially the filtered items move to the destination instead of simply filtering

**css properties used in the video**

```
.popularMovie{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(250px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}
```

The animation in the video basically just used only 2 motion.div with 2 layout attribute,
the css used is also copied but the effect is not reproducable
below is a code sandbox example that I made,

[Minimal reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-scale-correction-forked-3lmjuh?file=/src/App.jsx)

Comment: Please do not 1.) post code as image and 2.) post links without providing the essence of the content linked (links can break over time).

Comment: "simple" is subjective - there's a _lot_ of stuff that goes on behind-the-scenes when you use Framer, compared to, say, CSS's built-in `animation:` or `transition:` - so given the actual complexity involved, I would not call this a "simple layout animation" at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

1. Do not miss the `key` property of the inner component:

`<motion.div key={item.id} layout className="box">`

2. Make sure that `key` property is **unique** (e.g. DO NOT use something like `filtered.map((item, i) => <h2 key={i}/>)`)